# setar localização de scrol

Tags: html, css, div, rolamento

tenho uma div com overflow: auto; eu pressiso deixar o scrol dessa div no ponto mais baixo, para mostrar apenas as informações mais novas:

```css
div{
 width: 150px;
 height:80px;
 border: 1px solid;
  padding:5px;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
informação antiga<br>
informação antiga<br>
informação antiga<br>
informação antiga<br>
informação nova<br>
informação nova<br>
informação nova<br>
informação nova<br>
informação nova<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Esta dúvida foi respondida com uso de JavaScript puro [aqui neste fórum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)

Answer (score 0):

Como foi respondido [neste stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530829/auto-scroll-to-bottom-when-overflow-auto), é possível fazer isso com jQuery de forma bem simples.

**Edit**: Removi aquela animação desnecessária.

```js
var minhaDiv = $("#divOverflow");
minhaDiv.scrollTop(minhaDiv.prop('scrollHeight'));
```

```css
div#divOverflow{
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divOverflow">
    <div>
        informação antiga<br>
        informação antiga<br>
        informação antiga<br>
        informação antiga<br>
        informação nova<br>
        informação nova<br>
        informação nova<br>
        informação nova<br>
        informação nova<br>
    </div>
</div>
```